# Personalizar celda "TableViewCell" .xib con un collectionViewCell en su interior

Tags: ios, swift

Tengo una clase `TableViewCell` con su archivo `.xib`.
En la celda que aparece en el `.xib` le agrego un `collectionView` en el interior.

¿ Como puedo referenciar o usar el `collectionView` de esta celda de TableView para hacer uso de las celdas dentro del `collectionView`?

Dentro de la función `awakeFromNib()` intento hacer lo siguiente:

```
 self.collectionView.register(UINib.init(nibName: "CollectionViewCell",bundle: Bundle.main), forCellReuseIdentifier: "menu_collection_cell")
```

Pero me sale el error:

> "Cannot invoke 'register' with an argument list of type '(UINibm forCellReuseIdentifier: String)"

Comment: El error que te aparece es en compilar o cuando corres tu app?

Answer (score 1):

Digamos que lo que estás intentando hacer es posible aunque quizás a ojos de muchos se podría considerar una locura. Aún así responderé a tu duda.

Para hacer que un `CollectionView` dentro de una celda funcione, los `Delagate` y `DataSource` de dicho `CollectionView` deben estar implementados dentro de la clase de la celda, e aquí la locura.

Para ello el `register` debe estar dentro del `awakeFromNib` de la celda.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: ¬_¬ No entiendo por qué dices que es una locura, así es como están estructuradas las apps en base a rieles o carruseles (Netflix, Prime, SeeSo, Blim).